# Print new rows from a Google Sheets spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, printing

I am trying to have a Google Form submission that is accepted as a new row in a linked Google Sheet be automatically printed when it is imported to Google Sheets. Do I need multiple scripts or can this even be done?

I have tried a 3rd party app since I am not very familiar with writing the code myself.  The 3rd party app works, but it takes 15 minutes for the print to be sent.

Comment: Welcome. Are you planning to print to a printer or to a file (such as PDF)? My understanding is the the former can't be scripted, and that the later can.

Comment: This medium article might be a helpful guide for what you're trying to accomplish: [Learn to Magically Send Emails from your Google Form Responses](https://medium.com/@max.brawer/learn-to-magically-send-emails-from-your-google-form-responses-8bbdfd3a4d02)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a printer set up with Google print, that is about the only way to do it via Apps script. Check out [this post](https://ctrlq.org/code/20061-google-cloud-print-with-apps-script) by Amit. 
I don't use cloud printers, but if they have email addreses, then you could also email a pdf to the printer (assuming that capability exists).